# Smooth way to calculate index based on several variable comparisons in base R

Tags: r, dataframe

Example data to copy

```r
df <- data.frame(
  AA = c(100, 200, 300, 400), 
  X1 = c(2, 1, 3, 1),
  X2 = c(1, 3, 4, 1)
)
```

Based on the index of `AA`, and it's values, I would like to calculate the sum of indicators based on the condition `df$AA[i] > df[df$X1[i], c('AA')]` (here for `X1`) for every row on a fluctuating number of variables.

My probably naive approach is to use a for-loop, which works perfectly for a fixed number of variables (columns), in the given example `X1, X2`. My problem is that I do not know the number of variables beforehand. Theoretically, any number 1, 2, 3, ... is possibly.

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$index[i] <- sum(df$AA[i] > df[df$X1[i], c('AA')],
                     df$AA[i] > df[df$X2[i], c('AA')])
}
```

Which gives the desired output for a fixed number of variables `X1, X2`:

```r
df
#>    AA X1 X2 index
#> 1 100  2  1     0
#> 2 200  1  3     1
#> 3 300  3  4     0
#> 4 400  1  1     2
```

**Is there a smooth base R approach which translates my approach to a flexible number of variables X1, ..., Xn?**

Note, the reason why I am interested in a `base R` approach is my aim to extend an existing package, which is fully written in `base R`. So I would like to keep it like that.
Loops or `*apply`-family approaches are both very welcome.
I am aware of the fact that operations on `dataframes` are often considered to be slower. Since all variables `AA, X1, ...` are of the same length, a solution which does not rely on a `dataframe` structure would also be great!

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop through rows. You can use `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], function(x) df$AA > df$AA[x]))
#> [1] 0 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this correspond to what you're looking for ?

```
df$index <- apply(df, 1, function(x){sum(x[1] > df$AA[x[-1]])})
```

assuming that AA is the column 1 and all your Xi are all the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner will work especially because `df` is a data-frame:

```
df$index <- rowSums( # To sum over a non-specified number of columns
  mapply(
    df[,- which(names(df) == "AA")], # Everything except AA
    df[,"AA", drop = FALSE],         # Only AA, but in a data-frame
    FUN = function(index, aa) aa[index] < aa)) # Compare
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I receive `Error: unexpected input in: ...` by running this code right after `df <- ...`. Since I am unfamiliar with the used syntax, I cannot say if there is just a tiny peace like a `,` missing.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by the syntax that I used for the function : `\(x)` (R version > 4) instead of `function(x)` (works for all versions). I edited the code to use the regular syntax. Also, in my code, there is no "df <- ..." so maybe the mistake comes from there ? I updated the code too to save the result in the `index` column.